# TensorRT/TFlite sample implementation

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, tensorrt

Having a trained '.h5' Keras model file, I'm trying to optimize inference time:

Explored 2 options:

1. Accelerated inference via TensorRT
2. 'int8' Quantization.

At this point I can convert the model file to TensorFlow protobuf '.pb' format, but as a sidenote, it also contains custom objects of few layers.

Saw a few articles on TensorRT conversion and TFLite conversion, but I don't seem to find a robust implementation that's legible. Can someone explain how that's done (TFLite/Keras Quantization or TensorRT) to use the same model for faster inference.

(Open for other suggestions to improve inference speed supported in TensorFlow and Keras)

Answer (score 0):

This is the user guide on how to use TensorRT in TF: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html

This talk explains how TensorRT works in TF: https://developer.nvidia.com/gtc/2019/video/S9431

Note that TensorRT also supports INT8-quantization (during training or post-training).

This blog post also has kind of the same content: https://medium.com/tensorflow/high-performance-inference-with-tensorrt-integration-c4d78795fbfe

This repository has a bunch of examples showing how to use it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt

Comment: Thanks. But these are the same articles I was pointing to, in the question. None of these seem like a straightforward explanation to implement TRT.